# Bug: Spoiler markdown not behaving as expected!

Tags: bug, design

I had a little trouble formatting this question ([How to play when you hit a straight](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/5727/88)) to include a spoiler, so as to obscure the results from immediate view. The issue is that when including card images, (eg. J♣8♠) the silhouette of the cards are still visible, meaning I've had to input plain text rather than the much more visually intuitive suit images.

How do we go about fixing this?

p.s We need a Hand History Converter! See [**here**](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/a/215/88)!

---

Edit (6th April 2015): Still having this issue; changed post [**here**](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/5797/88).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when I was editing that very same question. In the end I gave up adding a spoiler, although I think now that it was the wrong decision.

We should probably report it as bug on Meta.SE.

UPDATE: [Bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250818/card-images-in-spoiler-tag-are-incorrectly-revealed-on-poker-stackexchange) added.

Comment: Is that where it needs to be reported? If so, go for it if you have time. If I don't see you've added a "bug report", I'll do it asap.

Comment: @TobyBooth I added the bug report, see my update.